# Unable to deploy contract on Besu network(docker) using dynamic IP

Tags: truffle-migration, truffle-deployment, docker, besu, networking

I am stuck with a weird situation. I create a local Ethereum network with Hyperledger Besu in docker environment. I try to deploy contracts to a rpc node using Truffle(different container in same docker network).

1.) When I have static IP configured for Besu nodes in the docker-compose, and I use the service name in truffle, contract deployment goes through fine.

2.) If I do not configure static IPs, in the docker-compose, for some reason the contract deployment is stuck. Why?

I have tried to see if there is network connectivity issue. Pinged the Besu node via hostname and IP(dynamically allocated by docker) which went through.
Here's the trailing logs I see, post which it is indefinitely stuck -

```
truffle-envt-besu-setup |
truffle-envt-besu-setup | 1_initial_migration.js
truffle-envt-besu-setup | ======================
truffle-envt-besu-setup |
truffle-envt-besu-setup | Deploying 'Migrations'
truffle-envt-besu-setup | ----------------------
truffle-envt-besu-setup | > transaction hash: 0x1a673f0f62c4f0690eb444d4922cd257b16f72bfff3e4d0362a50f3f9353ede6
truffle-envt-besu-setup | - Blocks: 0 Seconds: 0
```

Here's a snippet of the docker-compose -

```
 node2.eth.local:
    image: hyperledger/besu:1.3.9
    command: >-
      --data-path=/var/lib/besu --genesis-file=/var/lib/besu/genesis.json --rpc-http-enabled 
      --rpc-http-host=0.0.0.0 --rpc-ws-enabled --rpc-ws-host=0.0.0.0 --discovery-enabled=false 
      --p2p-host=0.0.0.0 --rpc-http-api=ETH,NET,WEB3,DEBUG,MINER,ADMIN,TXPOOL,CLIQUE 
      --rpc-ws-api=ETH,NET,WEB3,DEBUG,MINER,ADMIN,TXPOOL,CLIQUE --rpc-http-cors-origins='*' 
      --host-whitelist='*' --min-gas-price=0
    ports:
      - 8545:8545
      - 8546:8546
    volumes:
      - './besu/node2:/var/lib/besu'
    networks:
      local_net:

  rpc.node2.eth.local:
    image: pegasyseng/ethsigner:0.4.0
    command: >-
      --chain-id=12345 --downstream-http-host=node2.eth.local --downstream-http-port=8545 
      --http-listen-host=0.0.0.0 --http-listen-port=8555 file-based-signer 
      --password-file=/var/lib/ethsigner/password.txt --key-file=/var/lib/ethsigner/keystore/account.txt
    ports:
      - 8555:8555
    volumes:
      - './ethsigner/node2:/var/lib/ethsigner'
    depends_on:
      - node2.eth.local
    networks:
      local_net:

networks:
  local_net:
    driver: bridge
```

Here's a snippet of the truffle-config.js file -

```
     besu_docker: {     
            host: "rpc.node2.eth.local", 
            network_id: "*",
            port: 8555,
            gas: 4500000,
            gasPrice: 0
       },
```

Is there something obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have an error in your `truffle-config.js`
The port should be `8545` instead of `8555`.

Comment: Hey thanks @Abdelhamid for looking through. But that's not an issue as it works perfectly fine with the same ports for a dynamic IP. On a second note, I have realized that the static IP has something to do with the configuration in the genesis.json file. Once I have clarity, I will post a resolution here.